# How i can to do a dynamic resize respect to width of the browser window

Tags: css

In CSS all size of layout are in EM. In body i have setted size in pixel. Is possible modify dinamically it in base to size of the browser-window (width)?
The result that i search is that of resize all layout respect to width of browser-Window.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you try using **width: 100%;**? It automatically adjust the width.

Comment: can I know what is the size of the browser-window (width)?

Comment: I don't understand. I have something as:
body { font-size: 16px }
.myclass { width: 5em }
How i should use in body it? I want modify dinamically about property "font-size" on resize of the browser, so that all content into Window is automatically resized.

Comment: so you want to resize the font dynamically not the body or browser-window (width)?

Comment: Hello, try to explain better with a example. I load a web-page. All element of web-page are ok. Well, when user resize Windows of the browser automatically all element of web-page should to be resized proportionally.
I have uses em as unit of measure for all element of webpage and setted to 16px the font-size on the body. 
The problem so, is that when user resize all is fix (blocked to 16px as defined in body).
Better for give more idea, is an effect to "zoom" where more big is size Window and more big are element of it, and more small is size of window and more small are element of it.

Comment: Since you didn't explain it well, you should vote up back to me, because I haven't answered wrong. And you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calc method in css, [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is MDN document. It is supported almost all recent browsers, [Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) is Browser support graph.

Ex

```
width: calc(100% - 1em);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the css to

```
         width : 100%;
```

it will always fit to the browsers width

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can do this using the `calc` function. Ex:

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```